How to run translation or object animator or any other animation in another thread or background?
I want to run this type of animations in background when this method is call then start immediately without any delay and without freezing ui or main thread.
when is call this moethod then play music, start animation and after complete animation view deletion and creation  process is running then i saw delay and ui freezing.
    public void stackToStack(ArrayList<Card> subString, int targetX, boolean fromUndo) {
        System.out.println("Size ==> " + subString.size());
        Stacks targetStack = mainStacks.get(targetX);
        ArrayList<Float> getYPositions = getYPosition(targetStack,false);
        if (!fromUndo) {
            Music.move();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < subString.size(); i++){
            float xPos = (targetX * cardWidth);
            float yPos = getYPositions.get(targetStack.indexOf(subString.get(i),-1,1));

            CardView cardView = mainRelative.findViewWithTag(subString.get(i).getCard());
            cardView.setZ(1);
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, xPos - cardView.getX(), 0, yPos - cardView.getY());
            animation.setDuration(animationSpeed);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            cardView.startAnimation(animation);
            int finalI = i;
            animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    if (finalI == subString.size()-1) {
                        StacksView stacksView = new StacksView();
                        stacksView.addViews();
                        isNewClick = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
        }
    }



Hi, welcome to SO! Not sure I follow your question. Animation must always run in the main thread (OK, you can offload complex computation to a background thread and update the UI on the  main thread - but that's not relevant here). Is Music.move() blocking the UI thread?

no
public static void move() {         if (music) {             backgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {                 @Override                 public void run() {                     if (music) {                         movePlayer.start();                         movePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(currContext, R.raw.g_card_move);                     }                 }             });         }     }
